# How to include python support while installing vim using AAP?

Tags: python, vim

I wanted to install the plugin "You Complete Me" which needed latest vim (with all the patches). So I installed vim using AAP (http://www.a-a-p.org/ports.html). But the vim that got installed does not have python support which again, is a requirement for this plugin.

It is mentioned that we have to add the configuration arguments in 'config.arg' file (inside the main install directory), but I don't know what arguments to use?

If anyone has done this, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that AAP works with Python 2.6 or older - [see this thread on aap mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=200904062015.n36KFPf3030585%40moolenaar.net&forum_name=a-a-p-develop). I've tried with Python 2.7 and it didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the problem cos AAP works properly in my case. Vim gets installed fine but without the python support.

Comment: I agree that it is not the problem; instead, it is just a reminder that you need Vim with python 2 support, not python 3 (both options are described on ZyX answer).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know anything about AAP, but when manually building I need one of the following to get python support:

1. On linux when building for the host system I need to add the following arguments to `./configure` call: `--enable-pythoninterp=yes` or `--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic`. If you want to compile with Python 3 use `--enable-python3interp=(yes|dynamic)`.
2. On linux when crosscompiling for the windows host I need `PYTHON` make variable set to python directory (e.g. `/home/zyx/.wine/drive_c/Python27`) and `PYTHONINC` set to `-I{path_to_include_directory}` (e.g. `-I/home/zyx/.wine/drive_c/Python27/include`). You need to replace `PYTHON` with `PYTHON3` if you want to use Python 3. (Example commandline: `cd src && make -f Make_ming.mak FEATURES=HUGE CROSS_COMPILE=i686-pc-mingw32- PYTHON=/home/zyx/.wine/drive_c/Python27 PYTHONINC=-I/home/zyx/.wine/drive_c/Python27/include GUI=yes gvim.exe`).

If AAP is using `./configure` you should use the first variant, if it uses `make -f` you should use the second (assuming variable names are consistent across makefiles which is much likely).

Comment: I tried what you said, and a few other things, but nothing worked for me. I guess I'll just have to install vim from source with all the patches.